# Why I am getting different HttpResponse than browser in android?

Tags: android, xml, web-services, httpclient

I am trying to get simple HTTP response from this URL : http://realtorsipad.demowebsiteonline.net/eventsfeed.php

But surprisingly it not returning expected XML response rather returning another HTML page!

I am not being able understand what is issue.

Here is sample activity :

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {
    String parsingWebURL = "http://realtorsipad.demowebsiteonline.net/eventsfeed.php";
    String line = "";
    Document docXML;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        line = getXML();
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------
    public String getXML() {
        String strXML = "";
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(parsingWebURL);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            strXML = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            return strXML;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strXML;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably perform a GET request instead a POST one.

Comment: Same result return with GET request to.

Comment: I just tried it and my anti-virus kicked in and displayed a warning HTML page back. Check the HTML you get back and see if it's that.

Comment: It gives www.google.com page HTML in response!

Comment: What if you enter the url inside the device browser? Are you sure is not a DNS issue?

Comment: In device browser it redirects to google.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not your code per se, it's the site, it responds with a lot of redirects when the request is made with a mobile user-agent.

To replicate a desktop browser, change your user agent string. Like so:

```
public String getXML() {
    String strXML = "";
    try {

        final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, true);
        HttpClientParams.setCookiePolicy(params, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20131011 Firefox/23.0");

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(parsingWebURL);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        strXML = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        return strXML;
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strXML;
}
```

Comment: They follow the redirects.

Comment: @Nik88 I edited my response - the above works for me, hope it works for you!