# Android Getting different HttpResponse than

Tags: android, json, httpresponse

I'm trying to get a HTTP response from this URL : 
http://maps.google.com/maps?cid=6578389740751741251&q=a&output=json

It's supposed to be a JSON object. 
I'm my app, i'm getting an JSON object, but it's not the expected one...

Response in app start with :

> while(1);{title:"a - Google Maps",url:"/maps?q=a\x26ie=UTF8\x26hq=a\x26hnear=",urlViewport:false,ei:"NJr1VO62HuHCiAaQjYHgAQ",form:{selected:"q",q:{q:"a",what:"a",near:""}
>   ...

Response in Chrome on computer and Firefox on Android start with :

> while(1);{title:"Google Maps",url:"/maps?cid=6578389740751741251\x26q=a\x26ie=UTF8\x26hq=\x26hnear=
>   ...

I read the toppic linked above, and change the User Agent in my code, but it didn't make any change : 
[Why I am getting different HttpResponse than browser in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121123/why-i-am-getting-different-httpresponse-than-browser-in-android)

Here is my code :

```
final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, true);
HttpClientParams.setCookiePolicy(params, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, 
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20131011 Firefox/23.0");

String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?cid=6578389740751741251&q=a&output=json";
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
String text = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Edit :
Here is the start of the JSON object on my computer (after stripping the 'while(1)' on the beginning) :

> title: "Google Maps",
>     url: "/maps?cid=6578389740751741251\x26q=a\x26ie=UTF8\x26hq=\x26hnear=",
>     urlViewport: false,
>     ei: "H5H0VN_DDMW68wPF4ICgAQ",

And the JSON object from the Android app :

> title: "a - Google Maps",
>     url: "/maps?q=a\x26ie=UTF8\x26hq=a\x26hnear=",
>     urlViewport: false,
>     ei: "NJr1VO62HuHCiAaQjYHgAQ",

Comment: How ever you can't do anything with that JSON, because it's an INVALID ONE.

Comment: Actually I'm erasing the first characters (while(1);), and it give me a valid json (I can load it into a JSonObject without problem.

Comment: Oho, So What's your problem now ?

Comment: Well, I cannot trying to make a request on a Google site to get the latitude and longitude from a cid. In the pc, I have the correct json response. On my app, I get a response that give me an address in USA rather than in France...

Comment: Well, I just tried your request on **PC** and i'm getting same response like you in **Android**.
Probably the difference you see caused by cookies or settings of your browser?

Comment: im worried if you are using invalid cid

Comment: That's pretty weird. Can you send me the file you get from the request  pls ? 
At first i thought it was because of user agent that Google is sending me a different response, that's why i added in my code the httpClient.getParams().setParameter

Comment: Ok, I'm making some progress, with the help of Charles Proxy (to capture all HTTP traffic from phone). It seems that when i'm making a request with a CID, there is a first response with a Location "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=a&output=json". My cid is lost, and that's why i'm getting incorrect response.
Here is a screenshot of Charles : http://i.imgur.com/IQyQhdW.png and http://i.imgur.com/F7yrLZq.png